# 404 not found while indexing xml file in solr

Tags: xml, solr, indexing

Hi I am getting Http error 404 while indexing a xml  saying problem accesing./solr/#/myproject/update  Reason Not Found

Any one have any clue about this.

Thanks

Comment: what is ./solr/#/myproject/update  ???????? http url ???? whats # in it ?? how are you uploading ???

Answer (score 1):

If you want to insert data in your Solr you need to execute a curl command.

1. You need to install `php5-curl` module on your computer / server
2. Solr must be running
3. You need an xml file with your data with the same fieldnames than your schema.xml

Open a terminal and execute this :

```
curl yoursolrURL/update -H "Content-type:text/xml" --data-binary @yourfilewithdata.xml
curl yoursolrURL/update -H "Content-type:text/xml" --data-binary "<commit/>"
curl yoursolrURL/update -H "Content-type:text/xml" --data-binary "<optimize/>"
```

That's how I do it. Tell me if this helped you.